# Работа с данными из разных классов

Tags: android, kotlin

Приложению требуется получить информацию и разрешения экрана. Эти данные могут использоваться в нескольких классах, фрагментах и активити.

Получается, их нужно поместить туда, откуда они наверняка будут доступны, ведь постоянно создавать экземпляр класса, отдавая ему windowManager, нет возможности.

Сейчас есть один вариант: хранить данные в `shared preferences`. Например, писать туда при первом запуске и забыть.

Но есть ли другие варианты без записи в ROM?

Comment: Ну тогда записывайте в СУБД, хотя это тоже не вариант. А зачем вам собственно каждый раз создавать экземпляр класса? Создайте Singleton

Comment: Нет никакой проблемы один раз при запуске получать все данные от системы и хранить их в памяти. Зачем сохранять то, что уже хранит ОС.

Comment: Да, соглашусь. Однако именно в этом и заключается вопрос: как сохранить данные, чтобы они были всегда доступны, - до закрытия приложения, конечно.

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте класс Display и запрашивайте у его статического метода размеры экрана, передавая в параментрах контекст. Как-то так:

```
class Display{
    companion object{
        var displayMetrics: DisplayMetrics? = null

        fun getDPI(Context context): Float {
            if(displayMetrics == null)
                 displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()
            return displayMetrics?.xdpi * displayMetrics?.ydpi
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Разве в Kotlin есть `static`?

Comment: Не обратил внимание, что речь про котлин. Поправил ответ. Так будет работать так же, как и статик в java. Или можно singleton сделать

Comment: Ошибка компиляции: `displayMetrics` может быть null. Хотя, судя по коду, это едва ли возможно.

Comment: return displayMetrics!!.xdpi * displayMetrics!!.ydpi или return displayMetrics?.xdpi * displayMetrics?.ydpi

Answer (score 0):

Создайте класс-синглтон, делайте его экземпляр на старте приложения, скармливайте ему все необходимые данные и используйте где нужно...

Например, делаем класс

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class DisplayInform {

    private static DisplayInform instance = null;
    private Context context;

    private DisplayInform(Context context) {}

    public static DisplayInform getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DisplayInform(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public Point getDisplaySize() {
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point displaySize = new Point();
        display.getSize(displaySize);
        return displaySize;
    }

}
```

и используем в активити:

```
private int x = DisplayInform.getInstance(this).getDisplaySize().x;
```